# Right Align Caption with singlelinecheck

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, captions

I use `singlelinecheck=true` with the `caption` package to get small captions centered. However, I would like to be able to also get the single line captions to be left or right aligned. Getting them left aligned is obtained via

```
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}%
```

as I have done in Figure 1. And if the caption was longer things would still work in this case.

How do get the single line caption of Figure 2 to be right aligned (but only if it is a single line caption)?

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{%
    format=plain,%
    textformat=period,
    justification=RaggedRight,
    singlelinecheck=true,
}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \captionsetup{width=0.95\linewidth}%
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}%
    \captionof{figure}{Caption on Left}%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \captionsetup{width=0.95\linewidth}%
    \captionof{figure}{Caption on Right}%
\end{minipage}%

\medskip\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \captionsetup{width=0.95\linewidth}%
    \captionof{figure}{Caption Centered}%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \captionsetup{width=0.95\linewidth}%
    \captionof{figure}{Caption taking up full width}%
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Like this `\captionsetup{justification=raggedleft,
singlelinecheck=false
}` ?

Comment: @Bobyandbob: But that does not produce correct results if the caption is longer than a single line. See what it does to the caption of Figure 4.

Comment: Is there a way to do this exact same thing, but for text outside a `\caption`? For example, to force a `minipage` filled with text to behave like this?

Comment: @Jim As that is unrelated to captions, it would be better if you posted a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the optional argument of `\DeclareCaptionStyle` to define the special behavior of a onelined caption for an own caption style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionStyle{mystyle}
  {format=plain,%
    textformat=period,
    justification=RaggedRight,
    singlelinecheck=true,
  }% all captions are left aligned

\DeclareCaptionStyle{singlelinecentered}
  [justification=Centering]% centered if single line and no `singlelinecheck=false`
  {style=mystyle}% other captions are left aligned

\DeclareCaptionStyle{singlelineraggedleft}
  [justification=RaggedLeft]% right aligned if single line and no `singlelinecheck=false`
  {style=mystyle}% other captions are left aligned

\captionsetup{style=singlelineraggedleft}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \captionsetup{width=0.95\linewidth}%
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}%
    \captionof{figure}{Caption on Left}%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \captionsetup{width=0.95\linewidth}%
    \captionof{figure}{Caption on Right}%
\end{minipage}%

\medskip\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \captionsetup{width=0.95\linewidth,style=singlelinecentered}%
    \captionof{figure}{Caption Centered}%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image}%
    \captionsetup{width=0.95\linewidth}%
    \captionof{figure}{Caption taking up full width}%
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works well. If it is easy, can you include an option where the caption is right aligned _with_ a specfic width. Eg, in Figure 2, how do I get the caption right aligned when the option `\captionsetup{width=4.0cm}` is also applied.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution with `floatrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow, caption}

\captionsetup{%
    format=plain,%
    textformat=period,
    justification=RaggedRight,
    singlelinecheck=true,
}%
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering\floatsetup{floatrowsep=qquad}
\captionsetup{font=small}
\begin{floatrow}\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}%
    {\caption{Caption on Left}}%
%%%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}%
    {\captionsetup{justification=raggedleft}\caption[]{Caption on Right}}%
\end{floatrow}%
\par
\vspace{3ex}
%%%%%%
\begin{floatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
 \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}%
 { \caption{Caption Centered}}%
 %%%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
 \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}%
 {\captionsetup{format=hang}\caption[]{Long caption taking up full width}}%
\end{floatrow}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]